# There is duplicate content in JSON, I want to find a better way to edit JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json

I used notepad to look at JSON, but it was convenient, but I wanted to write an algorithm to handle the duplicate content in JSON.

For example, line 1500-1506 describes an object, which is exactly the same as the object in lines 2700-2706, except that the ID is different.

I want to iterate over these duplicate objects and delete the extra ones. Are there any good methods?

UPDATE：My JSON file is too long, so I cannot attach the code in this question. If  someone wants to know my JSON file, may you give me your mailbox and I send it to you? I will describe where is the duplicate content.

Comment: You need to elaborate on the question, add a sample and explain further what kind of objects, their structure etc. It is too generic right now.

Comment: If you can share json structure, may be ans would be more correct. For simple jsons this may work.

removeDuplicateKeys(jsonObject) {
    let hashOfKeys = {};
    for (var key of Object.keys(jsonObject)) {
        let value = jsonObject[key];
        console.debug(key + " -> " + value);
        if(hashOfKeys[value]) {
            delete jsonObject[key];
            console.debug('Removing key : '+ key + ' ,with value : ' + value);
        } else {
            hashOfKeys[value] = true;
        }
    }
}

Comment: My JSON file is too long, so I cannot attach the code in this question. If someone wants to know my JSON file, may you give me your mailbox and I send it to you? I will describe where is the duplicate content.

Comment: Update! Now I have developed an APP can compress JSON file. I use C# to finish it. This software can batch compress all JSON files in a folder, but the speed is relatively slow. This is mainly because my recursive algorithm is not so fast. Someday in the future, I will put the package on Github, thank you again for your excellent programmers for your suggestions!